# How to force instantiate a method in shared object?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I'm writing a library, with some API. The library, doesn't call all method' which it defines. After I finished to compile the .so file I wrote a program to use the API with the library. Since I compile the .so with -O3 methods which are not called are not in the shared object and when I try to compile the my test program, compilation passes but linage fails. Is there a way to force instantiate a method?

When I use `objdump -t libXXX.so | grep func` I get no output for the method the linkage fails with.

The method is implemented in the header (and must stay this way)

Comment: Are you sure that's your problem? You didn't forget to link the library with some object file? Are you sure it's your functions that are missing?

Comment: What do you mean _"instantiate a method"_ Functions are functions, and some are class member functions, and there might be non static class member functions, so what you're actually asking about?

Comment: Shared objects should contain all functions which are visible, whether they're used or not. Functions having static linkage, or in anonymous namespaces, could be removed if they're not used, but everything else is kept. Could you show the method(s) you think are missing?

Comment: "implemented in the header" suggests an inline function? Maybe -O3 has caused the function to be inlined everywhere in the library?

Comment: But I call from out side, I need it, and I don't think it is inlined because I use `-fno-inline` switch

Comment: To your deleted question "[Using shell output different number of data for each line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018536/using-shell-output-different-number-of-data-for-each-line)": `declare -a a; while read -a a; do for ((i=1;i<=${a[0]};i++)); do echo -n "${a[$i]} "; done; echo; done < file`

Comment: You are great! I came up with while IFS=' ' read -a array; do for x in `seq 1 ${array[0]}`; do echo -n ${array[$x]}; done ; echo ; done < /tmp/data. Now I see it is almost the same!